# timer_create function returning EINVAL

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel

I am writing a sample program where my main() will create a thread and then it will start a timer. When the timer expires, the thread should get the signal. This is on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

My problem is that timer_create() is failing and error number is set to EINVAL. My snippet of code for timer_create() is given below.

```
    /* Create the timer */
    sevp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD_ID;
    sevp.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
    sevp.sigev_value.sival_int = somevalue;
    sevp._sigev_un._tid = threadid;

    retval = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&sevp,&timerid);

    if ( 0 == retval )
    {
        printf("Success in creating timer [%p]",timerid);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error in creating timer [%s]\n",strerror(errno));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `threadid`? Are you sure its a valid id? Dud you by any chance use a pthreads id?

Comment: @PiRocks yes, I am using a pthreads id.

Comment: "As for SIGEV_SIGNAL, but the signal is targeted at the thread
              whose ID is given in sigev_notify_thread_id, which must be a
              thread in the same process as the caller.  The
              sigev_notify_thread_id field specifies a kernel thread ID,
              that is, the value returned by clone(2) or gettid(2)."

Important part is that you should use the kernel tid not the pthreads id.

Comment: Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: @PiRocks .. yes, I had to use gettid() instead of the pthread_self(). These are different. After this my code works. Thanks a lot. Please create an answer so that I can mark it correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the linux man page entry for `timer_create` with `SIGEV_THREAD_ID`:

> As for SIGEV_SIGNAL, but the signal is targeted at the thread
> whose ID is given in sigev_notify_thread_id, which must be a
> thread in the same process as the caller.  The
> sigev_notify_thread_id field specifies a kernel thread ID,
> that is, the value returned by clone(2) or gettid(2).  This
> flag is intended only for use by threading libraries.

The thread ID (`threadid` in the question code) needs to be a kernel thread ID. That ID can be obtained with `gettid`.

Comment: The standard C library doesn't normally provide `gettid()`, but you can `#include <sys/syscall.h>` and implement it as `static inline pid_t gettid(void) { return syscall(SYS_gettid); }`, for those who don't happen to know this already. (Unfortunately, we don't have a reliable way to map `pthread_t`s and `tid`s.)